# How does Turn server actually helps clients behind NAT?

Tags: turn

If a WebRTC client behind NAT cannot connect to other peer then it should use TURN server.
How that client actually receives stream from TURN server?

EDIT: Need to add this question also.

Why turn server is needed if we run media server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TURN server has a public ip and opens up a port. This avoids NAT traversal and the only remaining issue are firewalls that block UDP -- for that, TURN can be used over TCP or TLS.

When using a media server, TURN might not be required.
[This blog post](https://medium.com/the-making-of-appear-in/what-kind-of-turn-server-is-being-used-d67dbfc2ff5d) has some data supporting this argument but you might want to measure yourself.
Note that not using a TURN server requires a number of things on the media server side such as running all sessions on a single port (443) and implementing ICE-TCP.